# Como gestionar los Fragmentos: fragment already added

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy medianamente perdido con el tema de los fragmentos en Android. El problema es que no se como gestionar los fragmentos para que no me den error. Y tampoco se si lo estoy haciendo bien.

Obviamente he mirado la documentación: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es, pero no consigo aclararme. Y así mismo, otras páginas con ejemplos y tutoriales. Pero no saco ninguna conclusión definitiva.

Os dejaré más abajo el código de como utilizo yo un fragmento, que básicamente es para mostrar como un "cargando" moderno, a modo de fragmento, para que salga al centro de la pantalla. Una duda más, es como utilizar el FragmentTransaction, ya que hasta ahora no lo he utilizado nunca.

Tengo las variables globales:

```
private DialogLoadingFragment loadingDialog = null;
private FragmentManager fm = null;
```

Luego en onCreate():

```
loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Y cuando necesito mostrarlo:

```
private void showLoadingDialog()
{
    if (!loadingDialog.isAdded()) {
        loadingDialog.show(fm, "loading");
    }
}
```

Y cuando termina:

```
if (loadingDialog.isAdded())
{
    loadingDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Pero ni idea de si necesito utilizar el FragmentTransaction, o si tengo que utilizar:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (!fm.isDestroyed() && fm != null)
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

    if (loadingDialog != null && loadingDialog.isAdded()) {
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

El fragmento lo extiendo de esta manera:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String language = UApp.prefs.getString("preferenceLanguage", "");

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        if (getArguments().getBoolean("notAlertDialog")) {
            return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading_small, null);

    TextView textLoading = v.findViewById(R.id.txtLoading);
    ProgressBar pb1 = v.findViewById(R.id.barraLoading1);
    ProgressBar pb2 = v.findViewById(R.id.barraLoading2);

    pb1.getIndeterminateDrawable()
            .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(UApp.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    pb2.getIndeterminateDrawable()
            .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(UApp.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("english"))
    {
        textLoading.setText("Loading...");
    }
    else
    {
        textLoading.setText("Cargando...");
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setView(v);

    return builder.create();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading_small, container, false);

}
```

Y obviamente el resto de métodos están. Pero no los pongo para no llenar todo de código.

Y recibo este error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: DialogLoadingFragment{6b0facb #1 loading}
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment + 1916(FragmentManager.java:1916)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps + 765(BackStackRecord.java:765)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps + 2625(FragmentManager.java:2625)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether + 2411(FragmentManager.java:2411)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute + 2366(FragmentManager.java:2366)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions + 2273(FragmentManager.java:2273)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run + 733(FragmentManager.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7063(ActivityThread.java:7063)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 494(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 965(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

No tengo claro si mi código es correcto. Y la documentación no ayuda demasiado. ¿Cómo procedo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No coincide el codigo que muestras con el error que te aparece, segun tu codigo loadingDialog = null y en ningun momento deja de ser null por lo que deberia darte un null pointer exception. Pero el error es diferente, podrias agregar el codigo faltante e indicar en que linea se produce el error?